# NewCard screen from DrawerNavigator item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I hope i'm able to explain this properly, and that there isn't already an answer out there. It seems there is still a few design decisions up in the air for apps that have a StackNavigator nested inside DrawerNavigator.

What I'm trying to achieve: I have a link to a "Settings" screen in my DrawerNavigator, similar to a lot of apps. I will use Google Play Music as an example for what I want. Clicking on "Settings" sends you to a new screen with only a "back" / "done" button. The Drawer Menu is not accessible.

Question: How can I add a link in the DrawerNavigator that links to a new card/modal view? I'm guessing it can be achieved my some nested navigator stack, but I haven't been able to get anything that works.

Sample code:

```
const DashboardNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
})

const SettingsNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen}

// I thought adding 'mode': 'modal would give me the functionality
// I'm looking for my it doesn't

}, { mode: 'modal', initialRoute: 'Settings' })

const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: DashboardNavigator
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsNavigator
  }
})
```

There is a pull request to allow disabling the Drawer Menu on specific screens so i'm not really worried about that right now, but just navigating to a screen where `navigation.goBack()` takes me back to the last screen I was on (with the card slide animation).

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it with this, although I still can access the Drawer menu... Hopefully they add the ability to disable the Drawer soon.

```
const DrawerComponent = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SettingsView")} title="settings" />
    </View>
  )
}

const DashboardNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  SettingsView: { screen: SettingsScreen }
})

const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: DashboardNavigator
  }
}, { contentComponent: DrawerComponent })

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Root: {
    screen: DrawerNavigation
  }
})
```